# iPhone search bar design

Tags: iphone, interface, indexing, uisearchbar

I currently am implementing a search bar for one of my apps and I am having a problem with the indexed search overlapping it. I need to move the search field a little to the left so that way the index search is completely visible and not overlapping my search bar. I have tried a few things in interface builder but nothing is working. If anyone has a solution it would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is your search bar parented to your table view?  The screenshot below mirrors the Contacts app UI.[Search bar view hierarchy in Interface Builder http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/6286/searchtableview.png](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/6286/searchtableview.png)

Comment: Yes it is parented to my table view. We don't have a search display controller though.